# Close Votes Review - Edit and vote to close as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, vote-to-close

When reviewing close votes, clicking on "Edit" is considered as a "Leave Open" vote?

If the question is duplicated *and* can be improved through editing (not to make it unique, but only to correct grammar/identation/etc), I'd like to click on "Edit" *and* then vote to close as duplicated.

Isn't that a good idea? Is it currently possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my observations, Edit not only counts as Leave Open, it also aborts review and kicks the question out of the queue (preserving whatever close votes it had at the moment of review completion).

For an example, take a look at [this review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/close/40875): first two were votes to close, third is Edit and review is marked completed at this stage (question was eventually closed, but that was done outside of the queue):

> **Review completed Sep 30 at 6:56:**
>   Kilian Foth reviewed this Sep 30 at 6:56: **Edit**
>   MichaelT reviewed this Sep 30 at 0:48: **Close**
>   GlenH7 reviewed this Sep 30 at 0:19: **Close**

Given above, if you wish to close the question after editing, you need to also decide whether you prefer it to stay in the queue (in this case, don't use "Edit") or not (in this case, use "Edit" and keep in mind that it will be possible to close only from outside of the queue).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit a question while still voting to close you'll need to open the question up in a new window/tab to edit it and then just vote to close form the review queue.

The idea is that they don't want to encourage spending lots of time trying to work on a question if you know that even after the edit it's still not going to be a good question.  While it can on occasion be useful, it shouldn't be a very standard workflow.  If the question would still be closed there are most likely better places for you to spend your  editing time.  That said, if you really want to do it, all you need to do is edit it outside of the queue, which isn't that burdensome.

Answer (score 0):

This is bad UI, IMO.

A vote to close can be retracted, including based on other comments or (especially) on subsequent edits that improve the question.

A choice to edit, to try to improve a question, should **NOT** foreclose the ability to vote to close. That makes no sense.

The two contributions: edit to help improve and vote to close because currently not good enough, are orthogonal. I may well be able to improve a question, but not enough (e.g. for lack of info) to preclude voting to close. My edit may well encourage the OP or others to further improve the question, causing me to then retract my close vote.

A close vote is based on the question as it is now. An edit is an attempt to move the question forward so that it *might* become a useful one, worthy of keeping.

I frankly have a hard time believing that this review UI behavior makes sense to anyone.